# What is the equivalent for SavedRequestAwareWrapper.getRequest() in spring security 4.0.1?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am new to spring and I have been asked to port code written for spring security 2.0.4. With 4.0.1, I am getting compilation error for the following code :

```
private void printArgs(Object[] args) {
  for (int i=0; i < args.length; i++) {
     Object o = args[i];
     if (o instanceof SavedRequestAwareWrapper) {
        SavedRequestAwareWrapper w = (SavedRequestAwareWrapper) o;
        logger.info("HTTP METHOD: " + w.getMethod());
        try {
            BufferedRequestWrapper brw = new BufferedRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) w.getRequest());
            InputStream is = brw.getInputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[is.available()];
            is.read(b);
            String s = new String(b);
            logger.info("post body:\n" + s);
            } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
            }
    } else {
        logger.info(o.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that SavedRequestAwareWrapper is deprecated in 4.0.1. Can someone tell me the equivalent for the same?

Comment: What a contraption. The `SavedRequestAwareWrapper` is a `HttpServletRequest` instance so not sure why you need to get the underlying request and wrap it again...

Comment: What is the error you get, if it is deprecated you would get a warning not an error.

Comment: Not deprecated really, but package-private.

Comment: Don't check for that class, just check if it is a `HttpServletRequest` and just wrap that instead of checking only for this corner case.

Comment: It is a compilation error. It doesn't find the class org.springframework.security.wrapper.SavedRequestAwareWrapper in the 4.0.1 jar

Comment: I did what you asked me to, Deinum. It worked. Thank you!